# batch file IF vs ECHO giving different results

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this weird problem happening
I am downloading a a file using a wget, then set a var as first line of file, then comparing to string to verify the file. Weird thing is var is set as expected, echo works fien but when I use if to compare, var blows up. Look at example below:

```
set /p first_line=< c:\data.dsv
echo %first_line%
if %first_line% == SomefirstLine GOTO Success
```

When batch runs, echo gives correct var value, but in if it give first 3 lines, why is this weird thing happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably the line termination in the downloaded file. If lines end with 0x0A (linefeed) without a 0x0D (carriage return), the `set /p` will read until the first 0x0D, end of file or max length is retrieved.

`echo` command will output until the first 0x0A, but the variable contents are the three "lines", and it can be verified using `set first_line` to see the real content of the variable.

You can use

```
set "first_line="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\data.dsv) do set "first_line=%%a" & goto done
:done
```

Or if you prefer to read the file with the `set /p` method, then do that same processing on the retrieved variable to extract the required value

```
set /p first_line=< c:\data.dsv
set "first_first_line="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%first_line%"
) do if not defined first_first_line set "first_fisrt_line=%%a"
```

EDITED - It seems the OS versions affects the way it works.

The second proposed code was tested in a machine with XP and it worked, but in windows 7 it does not work. Once tested, the for command, instead of splitting the string on the 0x0A character, removes the 0x0A and the three lines are joined into one that is assigned to the variable. So, only the first option (with just the for loop) works on both versions.

Option 3 - To avoid reading the full file into memory, the output of the `set` command can be parsed to retrieve the real first line.

```
@echo off

:: get data
    set /p "first_line="<c:\data.dsv

:: show data
    echo(data retrieved with set /p
    echo(----------------------------------------------------
    echo(%first_line%
    echo(----------------------------------------------------
    set first_line
    echo(----------------------------------------------------
    echo(

:: get data 2
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set first_line^|find "first_line="') do set "first_line=%%b"

:: show data
    echo(data retrieved with for
    echo(----------------------------------------------------
    echo(%first_line%
    echo(----------------------------------------------------
    set first_line
    echo(----------------------------------------------------

:: test data    
    set "SomeFirstLine=...."
    if "%first_line%"=="SomeFirstLine" GOTO Success
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but will this for go over whole flat file, I have like 1.5 million records in there, that will be so much wastage of resources, time. I am a newbie and learning, let me know if I am wrong

Comment: @fdk2dublin, in the first code block, all the file is read into memory, but only the first line is processed. The second block of code uses the same `set /p` you were using, and then the retrieved data is splitted using a `for` command. In your case, the second approach is probably better.

Comment: Thanks MC ND, I am trying to use the second code snippet(for /f), but the length still tries to interfere & will not execute the and set the first_first_line, any help is appreciated in advance. or if there is any other quick way to fix this

Comment: @fdk2dublin, please see updated answer. It seems parser changes its behaviour with the os version.

Comment: @fdk2dublin, i've included a third option to avoid reading the full file into memory. Anyway, from recent tests with for command, i got a 280MB file loaded into memory in 0.11 second, and with the first approach it is discarded after the first line is processed. I don't know what is your volume of data, but if it is not really big maybe the single `for` command solves the problem.

Comment: @MCND: 280MB in 0.11 sec? That means - uhm - about 25Gbit/sec. Either you have a VERY quick disk, or it doesn't load the complete file.

Comment: @Stephan, Not really, there was a trick. If i have a old file untouched sice ... in the drive and run the `for` against it, it takes 1.4 seconds to load. But if the file has been downloaded (the case in the question) or transfered from network drive (my case) to local drive, it is still in the file system cache, and the 'ReadFile' operation (internally executed by the `for /f` command) is really fast.

Comment: @MCND: ok, that makes sense. 1.4 sec would mean about 2Gbit/sec, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Note the `double quotes` in the if compare - they protect it from `spaces` and `&` characters.

```
set /p first_line=< c:\data.dsv
echo %first_line%
if "%first_line%" == "SomefirstLine" GOTO Success
```

Comment: @foxDrive, i tried this before, but case is what MC ND has mentioned. I can make this thing work using the first method mentioned by MC ND, not sure why second approach (by MC ND)is not working.

Comment: Do you have spaces, `&` `%` or other poison characters in the string?  It's not the case that is the problem.